# What file name should I use to identify GitHubs userName/repoName structure for analysis on my local filesystem without nested folders?

Tags: github, github-api

I am analyzing GitHub repositories.
To keep track of the same resource throughout multiple calculations I want to use the userName and repoName in combination as an identifier.

First I thought a simple

*userName_repoName*

would do but apparently repoNames can now contain underscores as well (userNames can't so splitting after the first underscore would work okay I guess)

So my question is:

Do you have any advice for me on how to create a cross-platform failsafe identifier from a GitHub userName and repoName?
I want to avoid nested folders as it is easier to keep track of same-level folders than multiple nested ones (one user with multiple repos)

Comment: Do you have a requirement to be able to read the user name and repo name combination back later? If not, what about hashing the combined string? In fact, if you can always keep a table of hash values to names if necessary.

Comment: yes I want to read it back later and keep it as simple as possible.
I will probably use a sqlite or something similar to keep the mappings

Comment: Then you could keep a table matching the hashes. Though that said, I suppose I don't fully understand why underscores are not desirable for you; is it that you later want to be able to see all repos belonging to a user?

Comment: I will try underscores its just that I would have to split at the first one, because repositories allow underscores. That does not seem very elegant to me :D